# Custom validation in HTML5 for numbers CVC CVV

Tags: javascript, html

How to provide a custom validation for a number using HTML5

HTML

---

```
<input class="required" id="field" type="number" maxlength="3" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" name="cvv"/>
```

Here it is allowed to type in only one number. But max length doesn't work here.
Is there another solution ?

Comment: `<input type="number" pattern="\d{3}" maxlength="3" />`

Comment: `pattern="^\d?\d?\d?$"` or `pattern="^\d{1,3}$"` or `<input type=number max=999>`

Comment: Tushar here it will take no. but length validation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

use `max` attribute of the input [number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number_step)

```
<input class="required" id="field" type="number" max="999" pattern="([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])" name="cvv"/>
```

or even without pattern as

```
<input class="required" id="field" type="number" max="999" min="-999" name="cvv"/>
```

Comment: @guruvinder372 o/p is not coming according to requirement.

Comment: @Santosh where is the requirement given in your OP? if not, can you clearly call it out what you want to see?

Comment: gurvinder372 . Here clearly mention i want three digit and by the help of keyboard i can enter number only.

Comment: @Santosh using max attribute limits the valid entry to 3 digits only. you can specify `min` attribute as `"-999"`

Comment: @gurivinder at run time limit is exceeding.

Comment: @Santosh it will exceed, but it will also show an error, did you checked the link I had shared?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input), the maxlength works only if the value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password, tel, or url. I suggest you should use javascript validations for this particular case.

For a very simple example please refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_validate) link.

Comment: Hi hkasera this is suggestion. If you have any solution please post.

Comment: Hi Santosh, added a small example.